# keyup not working for multiple textareas

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using keyup function and that works fine for first textarea but wont work for others. Below is my html and javascript:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-5">
    <label for="Sympton" class="control-label">Observed Symptom</label>
<div class="output1"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-5">
    <label for="Why" class="control-label">Why?</label>
<textarea id="myTextarea1" class="form-control" name="Why" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
</div>        
<div class="form-group col-md-5">
    <label for="Sympton" class="control-label">Symptom 2</label>
<div class="output2"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-5">
    <label for="Why" class="control-label">Why?</label>
<textarea id="myTextarea2" class="form-control" name="Why" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#myTextarea1").keyup(function(){
        // Getting the current value of textarea
        var currentText = $(this).val();

        // Setting the Div content
        $(".output1").text(currentText);
    });

    $("#myTextarea2").keyup(function(){
        // Getting the current value of textarea
        var currentText = $(this).val();

        // Setting the Div content
        $(".output2").text(currentText);
    });

});
```

---

Im actually generating the code using php don't see how that would effect it. But yes works fine in fiddle. Could other Javascript conflict?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 

    <?php 
        if(isset($_SESSION['AnalysisCounter'])){
            for($i=1;$i<=$_SESSION['AnalysisCounter'];$i++){ ?> 
            $("#myTextarea<?php echo $i; ?>").keyup(function(){
                // Getting the current value of textarea
                var currentText = $(this).val();

                // Setting the Div content
                $(".output<?php echo $i; ?>").text(currentText);
            });
      <?php } } ?>
      });
```

Comment: Looks valid.  Can you replicate the issue in jsfiddle or in s.o.'s code runner? (Ctrl+m to bring up the S.O. code editor)

Comment: Yea, looks good to me too!

Comment: @Taplar LoL. I did that. Unable to replicate. `:P`

Comment: Yeah, I'm assuming there's something missing from the Q.

Comment: Works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/v5koxzky/

Comment: @charlietfl Works every where. Looks like that's crazy! `:P` Either the question is invalid or ... It cannot have one working and another not! LoL.

Comment: @PraveenKumar or OP failed to tell us that they are dynamically adding rows and only first one exists on page load

Comment: @charlietfl But why does he have it in the Source Code then? Good point tho!

Comment: no i got it to work fine in fiddle\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the issue *might* be because of dynamically adding the second and henceforth textboxes. So it is wise to [**delegate the events**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for this scenario to make it work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on("keyup", "#myTextarea1", function() {
    // Getting the current value of textarea
    var currentText = $(this).val();

    // Setting the Div content
    $(".output1").text(currentText);
  });

  $(document).on("keyup", "#myTextarea2", function() {
    // Getting the current value of textarea
    var currentText = $(this).val();

    // Setting the Div content
    $(".output2").text(currentText);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-5">
  <label for="Sympton" class="control-label">Observed Symptom</label>
  <div class="output1"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-5">
  <label for="Why" class="control-label">Why?</label>
  <textarea id="myTextarea1" class="form-control" name="Why" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-5">
  <label for="Sympton" class="control-label">Symptom 2</label>
  <div class="output2"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-5">
  <label for="Why" class="control-label">Why?</label>
  <textarea id="myTextarea2" class="form-control" name="Why" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
</div>
```

Comment: @owen Does it work in the snippet up there? Try "Run Code Snippet" and see?

Comment: @owen If you got it to work fine in the fiddle, can you kindly check the console for any errors? That might help.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) @ ?page=analysis&assign=5:42
?page=analysis&assign=5:278 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) @ ?page=analysis&assign=5:278

Comment: @owen Aha... There you are. Are you including jQuery?

Comment: Looks like you are also including other libraries? May be?

Comment: @owen Can you kindly post the full HTML source?

Comment: @owen That looks good to me bro... Any other `<script>` tags?

Comment: @owen You are executing the script before `jQuery` loads. Kindly put the script after `<script src="http://xeroharm.com.au/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>`?